# What does "Could not process download request: Failed to load properties for" in Artifactory logs mean?

Tags: artifactory

We see a lot of these errors in our Artifactory logs:

```
20161228 121638 [http-nio-8081-exec-22933] [WARN ]
(o.a.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:107) - Sending HTTP error code 500: Could not 
process download request: Failed to load properties for 314050135
```

what does it mean?

Looking closer at the warnings we see that in **most** cases the warning comes after trying to read a metadata-xml of some sort.

```
cat artifactory.log | grep http-nio-8081-exec-2441 | grep -A 2 -B 5 "Sending HTTP error code 500"
```

Similar to the below:

```
2017-01-04 09:02:48,788 [http-nio-8081-exec-2419] [DEBUG] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :98) - Entering request GET (10.67.6.51) /internal-release-rhel6/repodata/repomd.xml.
2017-01-04 09:03:48,791 [http-nio-8081-exec-2419] [WARN ] (o.a.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:107) - Sending HTTP error code 500: Could not process download request: Failed to load properties for 335095695
```

**Update**

We have increased the log level to get some context:

```
2017-01-04 09:01:05,955 [http-nio-8081-exec-2445] [DEBUG] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :98) - Entering request GET (10.67.7.101) /core-release/com/jeppesen/jcms/airport/maven-metadata.
xml.
2017-01-04 09:01:06,187 [http-nio-8081-exec-2443] [DEBUG] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :98) - Entering request HEAD (10.67.7.101) /ots-release/com/jeppesen/jcms/atriumorc/maven-metadat
a.xml.
2017-01-04 09:01:12,143 [http-nio-8081-exec-2373] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.GlobalExceptionMapper:48) - Failed to load properties for 165931919
org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: Failed to load properties for 165931919
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.DbPropertiesServiceImpl.loadProperties(DbPropertiesServiceImpl.java:113) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.DbPropertiesServiceImpl.getProperties(DbPropertiesServiceImpl.java:84) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.getProperties(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:1046) ~[artifactory-core-4.15.0.jar:na]
..... 

2017-01-04 09:01:12,143 [http-nio-8081-exec-2359] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.GlobalExceptionMapper:48) - Failed to load properties for 59628724
org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: Failed to load properties for 59628724
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.DbPropertiesServiceImpl.loadProperties(DbPropertiesServiceImpl.java:113) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.DbPropertiesServiceImpl.getProperties(DbPropertiesServiceImpl.java:84) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.getProperties(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:1046) ~[artifactory-core-4.15.0.jar:
......
2017-01-04 09:01:12,143 [http-nio-8081-exec-2422] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.GlobalExceptionMapper:48) - Failed to load properties for 26449553
org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: Failed to load properties for 26449553
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.DbPropertiesServiceImpl.loadProperties(DbPropertiesServiceImpl.java:113) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.DbPropertiesServiceImpl.getProperties(DbPropertiesServiceImpl.java:84) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.getProperties(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:104
.....
.....
.....
2017-01-04 09:01:12,180 [http-nio-8081-exec-2428] [DEBUG] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :204) - Exiting request GET (10.67.20.240) /api/npm/npm-all/grunt-contrib-copy/-/grunt-contrib-copy-1.0.0.tgz
2017-01-04 09:01:12,943 [http-nio-8081-exec-2416] [WARN ] (o.a.r.ArtifactoryResponseBase:107) - Sending HTTP error code 500: Could not process download request: Failed to load properties for 59815778
2017-01-04 09:01:12,948 [http-nio-8081-exec-2416] [DEBUG] (o.a.w.s.RepoFilter  :283) - Could not process download request: Failed to load properties for 59815778
org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: Failed to load properties for 59815778
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.DbPropertiesServiceImpl.loadProperties(DbPropertiesServiceImpl.java:113) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.storage.db.fs.service.DbPropertiesServiceImpl.getProperties(DbPropertiesServiceImpl.java:84) ~[artifactory-storage-db-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.getProperties(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:1046) ~[artifactory-core-4.15.0.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: the stacktraces provided are clipped. can you share the full stacktrace, especially if it contains the root cause (SQLException)?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is an SQL error when trying to load an artifact properties while trying to download the artifact. It can indicate some kind of a corruption in the database.
For more concrete details about the error set the log level of `org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter` to debug. This should provide a full stack trace in the log.